# Issue with Lockbits in DrawImage

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap, gdi+, lockbits

Looking for some much appreciated help. I'm trying to draw a smaller bitmap into a larger bitmap. I'm trying to use Lockbits to make the process go faster. But my .DrawImage function will not execute. The error is a general GDI+ error (Unhandled Exception). This is my code snippet. What am i doing wrong? The Misc.Lockbitmap is verified to work so i don't think the error is there, but I can put that code up here as well if that helps.

I should add that this is part of a much bigger code. To clarify: I am able to use execute the line with .DrawImage if i disable the lockbits.

```
Dim largerFile As New Bitmap(BitMapSizeX, BitMapSizeY)
Call MiscClass.LockBitmap(largerFile, PixBytes, RowSizeBytes)
Dim GraphicsModifier As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(largerFile)
Dim currentPic As New Bitmap(smallerFilePath.Tostring) ' & ".jpg")
GraphicsModifier.DrawImage(currentPic, picAndLoc.XLoc, picAndLoc.YLoc, ComponentSize, ComponentSize)
Public Shared m_BitmapData As BitmapData   

' Lock the bitmap's data.
Public Shared Sub LockBitmap(ByRef bm As Bitmap, ByRef PixBytes() As Byte, ByRef RowSizeBytes As Integer)
  Dim bounds As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height)
  m_BitmapData = bm.LockBits(bounds, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
  RowSizeBytes = m_BitmapData.Stride

  ' Allocate room for the data.

  Dim total_size As Integer = m_BitmapData.Stride * m_BitmapData.Height
  ReDim PixBytes(total_size)
  Marshal.Copy(m_BitmapData.Scan0, PixBytes, 0, total_size)
End Sub
```

Comment: Whatever `MiscClass.LockBitmap` is doing, remove it. What you need is `Using GraphicsModifier As Graphics = ...` and `Using currentPic As New Bitmap(...) GraphicsModifier.DrawImage(...) End Using End Using`. See that the path is correct and that it represents a full path.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My goal is to try and modify the bitmap while the bitmap is locked. I am able to modify it as long as i don't lock the bits. I was hopping to make the executing faster by using lockbits.

Comment: It doesn't. That overload of `DrawImage()` calls `GdipDrawImageRect()` directly. There's nothing you can do to make it faster. `Bitmap.LockBits` is used when you need to operate on the internal bytes (to alter the Colors / apply a filter or a convolution / perform calculations etc.). Widely used to substitute `SetPixel()` when the number of operations is ~high. The GDI+ function already acquires an exclusive lock on the Bitmap bytes. BTW, is it correct to apply the same value (`ComponentSize`) to both width and height? Maybe use the overload that requires a source and destination Rectangle.

Comment: So, if you find this procedure slow, the *problem* is not in the drawing function, maybe it's in the way you're using the Bitmap(s). I can see you're not disposing of any of the disposable objects you create. Repeat this mistake some more times with large images and the whole *planet* gets slow, until it stops spinning.

Comment: If you're not _using_ `PixBytes`, there's really no point in extracting it. In fact, that function is dodgy as hell; it doesn't unlock the bitmap, and, to be useful it should really return the stride (byte width of one image line) as well.